# How to flatten windowed pcollections in apache beam? [Cloud Dataflow]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I try to stream data from pubsub to Datastore using dataflow.
I searched google provided template.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates

And notice the PubsubToDatastore doesn't work.
So, I try to debug this.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToDatastore.java

here is what I done.

- add errorTag
- add window processing(pubsub generate unbounded data and datastore can't accept unbounded data)
- add flatten(the method of write windowed data to datastore is none. so, I think unwindowed.)

here is my code.

```
    package com.google.cloud.teleport.templates;

    import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.DatastoreConverters.DatastoreWriteOptions;
    import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.DatastoreConverters.WriteJsonEntities;
    import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer.JavascriptTextTransformerOptions;
    import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer.TransformTextViaJavascript;
    import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.PubsubConverters.PubsubReadOptions;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;

    // added for errorTag
    import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.ErrorConverters.ErrorWriteOptions;
    import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.ErrorConverters.LogErrors;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TupleTag;

    // added for window
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.FixedWindows;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.Window;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Flatten;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionList;
    import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionTuple;

    import org.joda.time.Duration;

    public class PubsubToDatastore {
      interface PubsubToDatastoreOptions extends
          PipelineOptions,
          PubsubReadOptions,
          JavascriptTextTransformerOptions,
          DatastoreWriteOptions,
          ErrorWriteOptions {} // added

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        PubsubToDatastoreOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory
            .fromArgs(args)
            .withValidation()
            .as(PubsubToDatastoreOptions.class);

        TupleTag<String> errorTag = new TupleTag<String>("errors"){};

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        pipeline
            .apply("Read Pubsub Events", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getPubsubReadTopic()))
            .apply("Windowing", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5))))
            .apply("Flatten", Flatten.pCollections())
            .apply("Transform text to json", TransformTextViaJavascript.newBuilder()
                .setFileSystemPath(options.getJavascriptTextTransformGcsPath())
                .setFunctionName(options.getJavascriptTextTransformFunctionName())
                .build())
            .apply(WriteJsonEntities.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId(options.getDatastoreWriteProjectId())
                .setErrorTag(errorTag)
                .build())
            .apply(LogErrors.newBuilder()
                .setErrorWritePath(options.getErrorWritePath())
                .setErrorTag(errorTag)
                .build());

        pipeline.run();
      }
    }
```

when I run this code, the error occured.

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 11.054 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-20T17:55:49+09:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) on project google-cloud-teleport-java: Compilation failure
    [ERROR] /Users/shinya.yaginuma/work/DataflowTemplates/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToDatastore.java:[80,9] can not find an appropriate method for apply(java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Flatten.PCollections<java.lang.Object>)
    [ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<OutputT>apply(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<java.lang.String>,OutputT>) can't use
    [ERROR]       (Unable to infer the type variable OutputT
    [ERROR]         (The actual argument list and dummy argument list have different lengths))
    [ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<OutputT>apply(java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<java.lang.String>,OutputT>) can't use
    [ERROR]       (Since there is no instance of type variable T, org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Flatten.PCollections is not fit for  org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<java.lang.String>,OutputT>)
```

what can I do next?
Please give me advice.
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to Flatten the collection after the Windowing. It am guessing the Flatten operation doesn't do really what you think it does.

Here is what it says it does:

> Returns a {@link PTransform} that flattens a {@link PCollectionList} into a {@link PCollection} containing all the elements of all the {@link PCollection}s in its input.
>
> Flatten takes multiple PCollections bundled into a PCollectionList and returns a single PCollection containing all the elements in all the input PCollections. The name "Flatten" suggests taking a list of lists and flattening them into a single list.

If you have multiple PCollections from different sources for instance and you wanted to "flatten" that into the same PCollection, then Flatten is your tool. In this scenario you only have a PCollection (not a PCollectionList, i.e. a list of PCollections) so the Flatten operation won't do you any good. The first step gives you a `PCollection<String>` from the `PubSubIO.readStrings()`, the windowing `Window.into(...)` then gives you a *bounded* `PCollection<String>` from that first *unbounded* `PCollection<String>`.

I suggest you simply remove the `.apply("Flatten", Flatten.pCollections())` line and run your pipeline again. It looks fine otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see. I didn't understand what the 'flatten' do.